# Remove a string found in column 1 from column 2

Tags: shell, awk, text-processing

I have a very large excel file (150000 rows). For each row I have a string in column 1 that I need to find and remove from column 2.

```
Input column 1    Input column 2                     Output column3
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
dog3456           dog3456; cat2345; chicken3595      cat2345; chicken3595
sheep23349        bird2048; rhino2948; sheep23349    sheep23349 
frog248034        toad3956; frog248034               frog248034
```

Does anyone have any advice please?

Comment: Not my area, but fairly sure awk and other shell tools don't handle excel files (ie xls/xlsx). You may be better off using a tool like Python to process the file.

Comment: I've also got the file in a tab delimited and csv format

Comment: OK - probably possible with awk etc then. Other thing is your description and example don't match (First line of example matches description but line 2 and 3 show opposite behaviour). Which is it?

Comment: Did you try anything? Also, please edit the data properly, preceed the data with four spaces or use the `{}` in the editor. Real tabs would be nice.

Comment: Sorry, Iine 1 shows the correct formatting. Please ignore lines 2 and 3.

Comment: @chives, please wrap up your code in CODE TAGS a button `{}` which you will see during your post edit and let us know then complete requirements of your question.

Comment: What's your question? Are you asking for help with how to write code to do what you want? Or do you have code and want it to be improved?

Answer (score 0):

I decided you are exporting your two columns of spread sheet as tab delimited.

```
cat data.tab  
dog3456 dog3456; cat2345; chicken3595
sheep23349  bird2048; rhino2948; sheep23349
frog248034  toad3956; frog248034
```

and the third column is output by the awk script.

```
awk -F'\t' '{split($2,a,";"); for(i in a){gsub(" ","",a[i]); if(a[i]!=$1)printf("%s; ",a[i])}print ""}' data.tab
```

outputs:

```
cat2345; chicken3595; 
bird2048; rhino2948; 
toad3956;
```